# Anti-Piracy measures (freeware software)

Tags: software, licensing, eula

So I was checking out the license agreement of a software product that I acquired the past days and noticed this section, please notice it was freeware software:

> You agree that if you are found to be distributing unauthorized copies of this
> software, or if you are found to be using a copy of this software that was not
> licensed to YOU that you will agree to cover all applicable
> legal expense incurred by X in your prosecution.  You further agree that these
> costs should not be less than 20,000 Euro per event.

I found it weird to include such statement and I have not seen anything like that in the past. Is it common for a software company to take such measures against piracy even on a "freeware" product?

Sorry if this is off topic, first time posting here.

Comment: Is this common is off-topic. Is this legal/enforceable isn’t

Comment: @DaleM just to bring this to your attention, "free software", especially when uppercased as "Free Software" (but to a lesser extent also in lowercase) is not the same as freeware. Freeware is _typically_ proprietary software given away gratis. Free Software, however, refers to software following one of several licensing models which have certain properties. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) covers some of it.

Comment: You are right about that I will edit my post, by free I mean distributed freely not free in the way that you are also supplied with the source code and you are allowed to modify it in your way.

Comment: Hah, sorry. My bad. I had (wrongly) _assumed_ Dale had edited that into your question. Should have checked. Apologies for the noise.